# Filling a select not firing angular controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to fill an HTML select using angular. I tested the API and got something like:

```
{"Countries":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Andorra"},{"Id":2,"Name":"France"}]}
```

The HTML is the following:

```
<form id="form" method="post" ng-submit="submit">
  <select ng-model="model.currentCountry" ng-options="country.Id as country.Name for country in model.countries" ng-controller="CountryController">
    <option value="">Country</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Then I have the JS code:

```
var application = angular.module('Application', []);

application.service('CountryService', function ($http) {
  return {
    GetList: function () {
      return $http.get('api/countries');
    }
  }
});

application.controller('CountryController', function CountryController($scope, CountryService) {

  alert("Country Controller");

  $scope.model = {
    currentCountry: '',
    countries: []
  }

  CountryService.GetList()
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.model.countries = $scope.model.countries.concat(data)
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { });

});
```

Somehow not even the alert in CountryController gets fired.

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Can you supply the code/markup that is specifying the controller? Whether that is a route or if you are using ng-controller.

Comment: I am using ng-controller. See my HTML select code. On the end you have the ng-controller.

Comment: Ah, I missed that (didn't scroll right). I assume you have defined ng-app further up in the dom via: ng-app="Application"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the success handler in your controller you have....

```
$scope.model.countries = $scope.model.countries.concat(data)
```

So you are concatting the Countries object from your example JSON, change that to this:

```
$scope.model.countries = $scope.model.countries.concat(data.Countries)
```

This way you are concatenating the actual array of countries to your model.countries.

**Edit** here is an example [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:rfqcl9AHEoJZEEJxyNn2?p=preview) to play with

Comment: Thank you, that solved it ... And I was also missing the ng-app because I add it on a div which was not wrapping the div. I moved it to the HTML tag.